# How do you 'Vary for Traits' when wR and hR are the same in both portrait and landscape?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, constraints, uistoryboard, ios13

I am building a Launch Storyboard for iOS 13 compliance.

I am constructing the 'splash screen' from several images. It's the last one that's the problem.

To get the scale right in Portrait, I select the device range (iPad), and portrait, then click 'Vary for Traits' (all before any constraints have been placed on the ImageView)

After I make all the constraints to get it looking right on all iPad devices in portrait mode, I deselect 'Vary for Traits' and then change orientation.

Now the UIImageView is incorrect (rightly so) and so I click 'Vary for Traits' and set all the constraints to get it looking right for landscape.

Then I deselect 'Vary for Traits' and click on Portrait - but now all the portrait constraints are conforming to the landscape ones.

The problem, as I can see is that for all the iPad devices, they have the same wR and hR regardless of Landscape or Portrait...

Is there a way I can still have different constraints depending on orientation? Or am I going to have to do all this in code?

Comment: You can't do anything "in code" with regard to a launch screen. It's not part of your running app; it's something that the device shows _before_ your app launches. It is _not_ a "splash screen". It's just a very plain rectangle to cover the half second while the app launches.

Comment: Oh. That's frustrating. So is there any way around the wR and hR same for both orientations, but needing different constraints problem?

Comment: No but I would deny that you need different constraints. It isn't clear to me what you're trying to do, but a launch screen is a very simple thing and there shouldn't be any difficulty with this.

Comment: What's not clear? How can I explain it any better than by saying image looks correct in landscape with constraints set correctly for all iPad landscape devices, but the same image is too small when in portrait on the same iPad devices with the same constraints... How else can I explain it?

Comment: Well, I'd need to know what the constraints are, what the image view's `contentMode` is, and what the image looks like in portrait and what you don't like about it.

Comment: @iOSProgrammingIsFun - this is more of a **design** issue. Generally, for `wR hR` trait, design your launch screen centered horizontally and vertically, so it looks good in both orientations. Alternatively, make your launch screen a solid color and have your app go immediately to a VC where you can make adjustments via code.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks Don. I completely agree, this **is** a design problem. I have some artwork that is centred horizontally but needs to be scaled using the 'multiply' option of the constraints differently depending on orientation. I can't get it so it's right in both, so I've currently settled for correct in landscape (iPad) but wrong in portrait - where it is too small (wrong multiplication factor for portrait). I tried splitting the image into several pieces each with their own constraints but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth to others, I managed to get an acceptable compromise, buy removing some text from the central image and replacing it with UILabels that I could better 'scale'.

I also used different constraints (where previously I was keeping the main image and title / logo centred H/V with equal width/height to the background and then using the multiply to scale it) I changed them to having all edges 0 to the overall superview and then using the constants to move the top or left and right to get the 'scale' I needed.

It's now looking pretty good in all devices and orientations.

Thanks to everyone who helped.